# Mysqli Query Echo result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi I am trying to make status of user so it will check how many post this user has and echo out the result, it was working fine when I was using mysql but after converting it to mysqli it giving me some errors

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])){
        header("location:index.php");
    }

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){

header("location: index.php");
}
else {

?>

<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","user");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$resule = "SELECT count(ID) from save_data where username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'"
    or die(mysql_error()); 

$result = $con->query($resule);

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $row[0], $row[1];

?>

<?php }?>
```

**Error:**

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\status.php on line 30
```

Comment: `mysql_error()` will not work, replace it with `mysqli_error()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `$row[1]` from:

```
echo $row[0], $row[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the offset 1 is undefined. so its pretty simple that you should remove `$row[1]` from `echo $row[0], $row[1];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$row[1]` in `echo $row[0], $row[1];` because the `$result->fetch_array` will only fill the `$row[0]`, because the SQL Query

> "SELECT count(ID) from save_data where username =
>   '".$_SESSION['user']."'"

will only return one result if username is unique.

Answer (score 0):

What will be happened If your query doesn't return any values? So better you check

```
if($resesult)
{
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $row[0];// remove $row[1]  because it fills only the $row[0]
}
```